# Add a title ("advertisement") after dfp ad

Tags: google-dfp

I would like to write below the dft ad that "advertising".
but if I make a div manually, it is not ok, because the div is showing if the ad is empty (collapsediv)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a css class to the ad

```
.adsclass:before { content: "Advertisement"; }
```

Or just add the div manually , you should not have any collapsediv problems , just set the right size of the div.